# Python IRC bot, wont stop the loop

Tags: python, irc, python-3.4

Okay so it just keeps looping through this and I don't know how to stop it on Python3.4

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
dat = ""
try:
    s.connect(("67.220.79.37", 6667))
    while True:
        s.send(bytes("NICK Conscience\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        s.send(bytes("USER Conscience chat.frostwire.com ident :realname\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        s.send(bytes("PASS ********\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        dat = dat + s.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8")
        s1 = str.split(dat, "\n")
        for line in s1:
            line = str.rstrip(line)
            line = str.split(line)
            print(line)
            if (len(line) == 0):
                continue
            if(line[0] == "PING"):
                s.send(bytes("PONG %s\r\n" % line[1], "UTF-8"))
                s.send(bytes("JOIN #nerdrage\r\n", "UTF-8"))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Use a `break` or raise an exception.

Comment: Please consider (*unless for learning sake*) using a framework here that takes cares of all this. e.g: [circuits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/circuits) and [ircbot.py](https://bitbucket.org/circuits/circuits/src/tip/examples/ircbot.py) or [Twisted](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twisted) and [IrcLogBoy.py](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/ircLogBot.py)

Comment: @Christian Just a break at the end will work? do you know how to make it react to commands?

Comment: It depends, when do you want to stop the loop? But, as @JamesMills suggested, you should use an IRC framework.

Comment: @Christian It won't pong back if I put the break under s.send(bytes("JOIN #nerdrage\r\n", "UTF-8"))?

Comment: you're on 3.4.  use asyncio.  here's my attempt thusfar to get you started.  https://github.com/eevee/dywypi

Comment: You need to take the while loop out of your try/except. Then when you want it to quit, type `raise SystemExit` (so after your last `s.send`).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this *does not* answer your question. My recommendation is **not** to do this by hand but to utlize a framework designed for this kind of thing. See my comments above.

Here is a very trivial IRC Bot using [circuits](https://pypi.python.org.pypi/circuits)

It will also responds to a very simple command when privately messaged. `hello`. Anything else will result in a `Unknown Command` response.

[simpleircbot.py](https://gist.github.com/therealprologic/c2c6670f8d23b29f268b)

**Update:** If you still insist on learning how all this works and writing a trivial irc bot by hand I recommend you read: http://hawkee.com/snippet/2497/ (*or other similar articles ont he web*) and learn from this.

*Example pasted here for your convenience:*

```
import socket

network = 'irc.snm.co.nz'
port = 6667
irc = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
irc.connect ( ( network, port ) )
print irc.recv ( 4096 )
irc.send ( 'NICK botty\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'USER botty botty botty :Python IRC\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'JOIN #paul\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG #Paul :Hello World.\r\n' )
while True:
   data = irc.recv ( 4096 )
   if data.find ( 'PING' ) != -1:
      irc.send ( 'PONG ' + data.split() [ 1 ] + '\r\n' )
   if data.find ( '!botty quit' ) != -1:
      irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG #paul :Fine, if you don't want me\r\n' )
      irc.send ( 'QUIT\r\n' )
   if data.find ( 'hi botty' ) != -1:
      irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG #paul :I already said hi...\r\n' )
   if data.find ( 'hello botty' ) != -1:
      irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG #paul :I already said hi...\r\n' )
   if data.find ( 'KICK' ) != -1:
      irc.send ( 'JOIN #paul\r\n' )
   if data.find ( 'cheese' ) != -1:
      irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG #paul :WHERE!!!!!!\r\n' )
   if data.find ( 'slaps botty' ) != -1:
      irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG #paul :This is the Trout Protection Agency. Please put the Trout Down and walk away with your hands in the air.\r\n' )
   print data
```

**WARNING:** As duly noted (*See my previous comments*) doing this by hand is complicated and difficulty to get right. Doing things like reading an arbitrary number of bytes, blinding searching through those bytes is error prone at best and at worst unreliable. *Please use a framework!*.

Comment: I'm kinda doing it to learn syntax and the protocol I don't want to just bam make it easy ;p

Comment: Be prepared then for a lot of work and low-level Socket I/O as well as IRC protocol handling. Learning is fine!

Comment: Like there is no problem connecting it just floods the NS window by looping it, and now if I put break under the loop it won't reply the pong for some reason. python 3.4 grrr.

Comment: please don't learn from that article either; i'm pretty sure reading 4096 bytes at a time, searching blindly for strings, and then throwing it all away is not a great idea.

Comment: I refer to my original comments :) Don't do this by hand :/